# SQL UPDATE запрос c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Хочу сделать запрос на обновление данных. Вот мой код.

```
string query2 = "UPDATE Auth SET(login = '" + txtLogin.Text+ "', password = '" + txtNewPassword.Text + "', name = '" + txtName.Text + "' WHERE login = '" + txtLogin.Text +"')";
                                MySqlConnection MyCon2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                                MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, MyCon2);
                                MySqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command2);
                                DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
                                adapter2.Fill(table2);
                                MessageBox.Show("Данные обновлены");
                                this.Close();
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: А что возникает какая-то ошибка?

Comment: Добавляйте проверку на ошибки или ловите исключение и выводите информацию о ошибках которые возвращает БД.А так то проблем много, например подстановка значений переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, если в них будут содержаться кавычки то все сломается. Кроме того совершенно не понятно зачем после set открывается круглая скобка и почему она закрывается только после where.

Comment: Метод `Fill` запрашивает данные из БД в DataTable. То есть ему нужна sql-команда `SELECT`. А у вас `UPDATE`. Соответственно, используйте метод `Update` адаптера.

Comment: И ради всего святого, почитайте про параметризованные sql-запросы!